# Java+DOM: How do I convert a DOM tree without namespaces to a namespace-aware DOM tree?

Tags: java, xml, dom, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I receive a `Document` (DOM tree) from a certain API (not in JDK). Sadly, this `Document` is not namespace-aware. As far as I know DOM, once generated, namespace-awareness can't be "added" afterwards.

When converting this Document using a Transformer to a string, the XML is correct. Elements have `xmlns:...` attributes and name prefixes. But from the DOM point of view, there are no namespaces and no prefixes.

I need to be able to convert this `Document` into a new `Document` which **is** namespace-aware. Yes, I could do this by just converting it to a string and back to DOM with namespaces enabled.

**But**: nodes of the original tree have user-objects set. Converting to string and back would make a mapping of these user-objects to the new `Document` very complicated, if not impossible. So I really need a way to convert non-namespace DOM to namespace DOM.

Are there any more-or-less straightforward solutions for this?

*Worst case (what I'm hoping to avoid) would be to manually iterate through old `Document` tree and create new namespace-aware `Node` for each old `Node`. Doing so, one had to manually "parse" namespace prefixes, watch out for `xmlns`-attributes, and maintain a mapping between prefixes and namespace-URIs. Lots of things to go wrong.*

Comment: Did you ever make any further progress on this? I have a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you figured out that there is no easy way to do this. If you have an old-style DOM that thinks xmlns:foo="xxx" is an attribute and not a namespace declaration, there is no way to magically "upgrade" it.  You would have to either serialize/reserialize or manually walk the tree and convert those attributes yourself.